# Certified Sales/Service Consultant - Prerequisites

Tags: certification

Can someone tell me what is the prerequisite for Salesforce Sales Cloud/Service Cloud Consultant certifications ?.

I have completed DEV 401 but I am unable to register for Sales/Service Cloud certification examinations.

The webassessor is complaining that I have not met prerequisites but does not provide the information as to what those prerequisities are.

Comment: I remember hearing by word-of-mouth that an ADM 201 and DEV 401 certification has to be completed to take a Cloud Consultant Exam.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. @Eric's answer gives the correct prerequisite for a cloud consultant certification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following link states the prerequisite:

http://certification.salesforce.com/implementation-experts

> Current status as a Salesforce.com Certified Administrator

Are you a certified Administrator?